# Can I use select_related() with ManyToManyField on Django Models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-select-related

I have :

```
class Award(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

class Alias(models.Model) :
    awards = models.ManyToManyField('Award', through='Achiever')

class Achiever(models.Model):
    award = models.ForeignKey(Award)
    alias = models.ForeignKey(Alias)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

How can I have an `Alias` which has all its `achiever_set` and `awards` prepopulated?

```
>>> db.reset_queries()
>>> Alias.objects.filter(id="450867").select_related("achiever_set__award").get().achiever_set.all()[0].award.name
u'Perma-Peddle'
>>> len(db.connection.queries)
3
>>> db.reset_queries()
>>> Alias.objects.filter(id="450867").select_related("awards").get().awards.all()[0].name
u'Dwarfageddon (10 player)'
>>> len(db.connection.queries)
2
```

I'm going to need a lot of access to the award that an alias has already gotten (both the intermediate table and the awards themselves). How can I batch all of these?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Django versions 1.4 and above have [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for this purpose.

The [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method is similar to [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), but does not do a database join. Instead, it executes additional database queries and does the joining in Python.

Comment: How to achieve join effect when using the `prefetch_related`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not on Django 1.4, there's also the [django-batch-select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select) library, which works basically the same way as prefetch_related.